# Add the GameKit key to your info plist file (Error)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

I have an "Add the GameKit key to your info plist file" error on the Capabilities tab. What's that supposed to mean?

[image: Here is a screenshot:]

Comment: What did it do when you clicked "Fix issue"?

Comment: @rebello95 i didn't clicked it yet! i want to find out what is this first

Comment: Look at your `info.plist` file, click "Fix issue", and see what changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gamekit fix Info.plist
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVUev.png

> Just add and item in *Required device capabitilities* in your *Info.plist* .

From documentation:

> Include this key if your app requires (or specifically prohibits) Game Center (iOS 4.1 and later.)

More information here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this from command line (in a CI). Here's how I did.

```sh
# make a copy of the Info.plist
cp Info.plist before.plist

# open xcode and hit Fix issue button
# compare the results
diff Info.plist before.plist
```

result

```
<       <string>gamekit</string>
```

In more details

```sh
cat Info.plist | grep gamekit --context=3
```

returns this:

```xml
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
    <string>gamekit</string>
</array>
```

So one could use the following snippet with [plistbuddy](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) to do the same as the button from command line:

```sh
# Adds UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities item to Info.plist
# || true prevents command line from failing if key already exists
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities array" Info.plist || true

# Add <string>gamekit</string> to array (at index 1) in Info.plist
# considering index 0 is already there and contains armv7
# Running Add multiple times will append a new line each time
# Here, we do it only if not already present
if grep -q "<string>gamekit</string>" Info.plist; then
    echo gamekit already present
else
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities:1 string gamekit" Info.plist
fi
```